# .children(":first-child") - ajax - multiple first children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple yet strange problem - when I select `.children(":first-child")` multiple results are given, one alert after another.

```
//  ...

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                //alert(response);

                tinymce.get('geqqo-editor-new').setContent('');

                $('#geqqo-modal-new').modal('hide');

                $('#geqqo-modal-new').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    $('#timeline').prepend(response);
                    var new_status = $('#timeline').children(":first-child").attr("id");

                    alert(new_status);
                });
//    ...
```

How do I select ONLY the first-child (that is, the recently appended one) instead of multiple ones such as it is doing.

Comment: use :first instead...

Comment: Try using `:first` & please share your html code here if even `:first` doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: It's not an issue with the selector - `$('#timeline')` should only ever return one element with that ID, even in a nonconforming document, so `.children(":first-child")` should only return the first child of *that* element. The problem must lie elsewhere in this snippet (or possibly elsewhere in your code entirely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [one method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of on method and `:first` instead of `:first-child`

```
$('#geqqo-modal-new').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    $('#timeline').prepend(response);
                    var new_status = $('#timeline').children(":first").attr("id");

                    alert(new_status);
                });
```

Comment: That works perfect. I've never heard of "one" -- thats a new one for me. What did that do different?  ---- I'll accept your answer as soon as the timer lets me.

Comment: I've linked to the one method see details there, in short: to trigger the event only for once.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var new_status = $('#timeline').children(":first").attr("id");
```

While `:first` matches only a single element, the `:first-child` selector can match more than one: one for each parent.

Also you are binding same event to a element twice. You should use. `.one()` method instead of `.on`

```
$('#geqqo-modal-new').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
 /*code here*/
}
```

`.one()` attaches a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Comment: Yes, still very strangely it gives me two alerts instead of one: One alert is from the previous operation, the next alert is from the present operation. Were I to do it again, it would give me three alerts.

Comment: Do both alert's have same ID? if so that might be because you are binding the event to `#geqqo-modal-new` selector multiple times for every ajax request. You can fix that by using the `.one` method instead of `.on`

Comment: Thanks for that. C-link just stated that. never hear of "one" - thanks a lot.